# How can I calculate the power of turbine using enthalpy?

Tags: thermodynamics

In the entrence of the turbine and the exit we have the following properties:
enthalpy, temperature, volume and interne energy.

How can I calculate the work done? I don't think I can apply $ W = \int PdV $.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you been learning about the open system (control volume) version of the first law of thermodynamics?

Comment: @ChesterMiller No. Just closed systems.

Comment: I'm confused. Doesn't a turbine function by flowing gas through a device featuring a rotating shaft?  In that case, there would be gas flowing into and out of the system.

Comment: If you had learned about the open system version of the first law, you would know that the power delivered by the turbine is equal to the mass flow rate of gas through the turbine times the change in specific enthalpy.

Comment: @ChesterMiller. Thank you for your answer. I had this question on an exam of thermodynamics where open system thermodynamics is not included in the program.

Comment: Sorry to hear that.  Very unfair.  Maybe, out of interest, you might like to check out a thermo book that covers the open system version; they all have it.